# Consider I'm a 10 year old kid, explain what "linearly independent" and "basis" means

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

As the question states. Consider I am a child, explain what those concepts mean.

Comment: Linearly independent and basis of what? of vectors and vector space? so I should explain first the meaning of vector space, is not it?

Comment: 10 years old kids have no use for linear independence

Comment: "Something you will learn about in ten years or so when you study linear algebra"

Comment: Should we assume the 10 year old kid knows what vectors are?

Comment: Hm, say the vector is "some apples and some pears" and one may have e.g. $1$apple$+2$pears or $\frac{1}{3}$apple$+0.5$pears. So apple and pear is a basis. Apple and pear are linear independent in sense $1$apple$\ne x$pears $\forall x$.

Comment: Let me explain first that people will be much more willing to help if, at minimum, you use the word "please" instead of issuing commands.

Comment: Well, it depends on your background... If you are really 10 years old, and asking such questions, you probably have a background very different from what most people have at this age. Do you know what Groups, Fields, Vector Spaces are? Do you know what a linear combination is? Or do you just want to program some 3D games, and have only some geometric intuition? (I still cannot get used to the idea that some people begin posting stuff on MathExchange before they understand basic arithmetic, because for me the order in which I learned those things was so radically different...)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this question will frustrate you guys so much. XD. Asking for pleases and all this other stuff. Okay. Zev, pretty please, if you were to describe basis on linear independence to a 10 year old, how would you. ( I know what they both are BTW)

Comment: A parallelogram should suffice. And 10 year olds study those.

Answer (score 2):

Think in two dimensions first.  Think of vectors as arrows coming from the origin. Two vectors are linearly independent if they do not point in the same (or opposite)  direction.  In other words if they do not lie on the same line.  If they do lie on the same line then one of them can be written as a multiple of the other - in this sense the second one is redundant.

Now if you are in three dimensions then it's the same for two vectors, they must not lie in the same line to be independent, but it gets more complicated if there are three vectors.  If you do have three vectors, then if two of them aren't on the same line, then there will be one and only one plane that contains them both.  To have all three linearly independent you then need the third vector to point out of that plane.  If it lies in that plane then they are dependent and you can obtain the third as a combination of the first two - so in a sense the third one is redundant.

Now, if you have two vectors in the plane that are linearly independent, they are a basis for the two dimensional vectors space.  And if you have three vectors in 3-space that are linearly independent, then they are a basis for the three dimensional vector space.  Etc.  Does this help at all?

Comment: I think it's a very good explanation. Lets say we expanded it into 4 space, would it then be the vector that goes opposite the 'volume' of this structure?

Comment: @user121615 Yes, if you have four dimensions then three linearly independent vectors will "span" a subspace of 3-dimensions and you'll need the fourth to point outside of that 3-dimensional subspace.

Comment: I wonder if anyone could even imagine something like this. Haha. Seems pretty interesting

Comment: If you think real hard you can start to get a (visual) inkling of the fourth dimension, but I don't think many people can take it to the fifth dimension.

Comment: Whooa, how do you think of it?

Comment: Well you can't think of four right angles, instead you have to let the fourth dimension sort of point off in a conceptual direction, kind of like thinking in terms of many 3-D slices simultaneously.